# Windows CLI | What are the correct qoutes/syntax for this batch line

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, command-line-interface

```
set grabber="C:\grabber.exe"
for /f "usebackqDELIMS= " %%j in (`%grabber% -s file.txt -e "extract($raw,'grab=(.*)',1)"`) do set grab=%%j
```

My problem is that I get various error outputs with " and ' in one end or the other and the variable program never gets picked up correctly because it reports path cannot be found.

%grabber% is Xidel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, and also demonstrating the --output-format=cmd  parameter:

```
for /f %%j in ('^" xidel -s file.txt -e "grep:=extract($raw,'grab=(.*)',1)" --output-format^=cmd ^"') do %%j
echo The value of grab = %grep%
```

But, if your data is simply structured as an ini file you really don't need xidel:

```
for /f %%j in (' findstr "grab=" file.txt ') do set "%%j"
```

...this simply finds the line(s) in file.txt that contain "grab=" and converts it to a variable %grab%

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Xidel, but you may have to escape the closing parentheses and the equal sign with a caret `^`
The space is the default delimiter and doesn't need to be specified.

```
@Echo off
Set grabber="C:\grabber.exe"
for /f "usebackq" %%j in (
  `%grabber% -s file.txt -e "extract($raw,'grab^=(.*^)',1^)"`
) do set grab=%%j
```

Comment: So it's not only me who doesn't know that program, is there a grabber.exe in the root of C: ?

Comment: If I check with my echoargs program instaed of grabber - there is no need to escape anything, all args are passed as is. What environment are you working in?